# If I import a package into python, do I also have to important it's modules separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, import

Very simply, I'm reasonably new to coding, and I'm going through another person's code to understand what it is doing as I have to use it for data analysis but I notice that they do the following:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
.
.
.
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
.
.
import matplotlib.ticker
```

I thought that "`import matplotlib as mpl`" would import all modules contained in matplotlib and therefore there need to separately import the module "`ticker`" from matplotlib after this? I would have thought that they could just use `"mpl.ticker"` later on and it would work?

Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 3):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
```

Yes, this imports every top level function and class from the `matplotlib` package (and makes them accessible under the namespace `mpl`), but it **does not import any submodules it has**.

`pyplot` is a module in the `matplotlib` package. If one needs access to classes/functions from `pyplot`, it has to imported also:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

For the same reason you have to `import matplotlib.ticker` to be able to use stuff from that module with `mpl.ticker.Foo`.

Here's a quick demo showing that just importing the base `matplotlib` package is not enough:

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> mpl.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
>>> mpl.ticker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'ticker'
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot
<function plot at 0x0EF21198>
>>> import matplotlib.ticker
>>> mpl.ticker.Locator
<class 'matplotlib.ticker.Locator'>
```

Comment: Can it be imported like : `import mpl.pyplot as plt` ?   
 
Your answer is good, but you missed a part of the question : "could we just use "mpl.ticker" later on ?"

Comment: If you want to access `plot` in `pyplot`, Both `plt.plot([1, 2, 3])` `mpl.pyplot.plot([1, 2, 3])` will work?

Comment: @Astariul `import mpl.pyplot as plt` Won't work, you can't use an alias to a package when importing.