# Why is it not possiple to write from matplotlib import * and then matplotlib.pyplot.plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, import, module

I know [What is the difference between importing matplotlib and matplotlib.pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661876/what-is-the-difference-between-importing-matplotlib-and-matplotlib-pyplot)
is similar. But according to what Plasma commented there it should be able to write from matplotlib import * and then matplotlib.pyplot.plot . But as you can see I am only getting NameError. I know you can write from matplotlib import pyplot. But I only want to know why you cannot write like the picture of the program below:

[image: Why does this not work]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you are not importing matplotlib, but all the elements of matplotlib; basically the object matplotlib is not in the environment, but the children objects are.

Comment: BigBen - I tried that but it does not work for me.

Comment: But when I write from matplotlib import *, isn't then pyplot just one out of the many modules that I am importing. So from matplotlib import pyplot should just be one of the modules that * refers to, right?

Comment: Also, how do I access pyplot if I would only write import matplotlib at the start of the program?

Comment: BigBen - But what if I wanted to use several of the functions that matplotlib offers. I suppose I would write import matplotlib or from matplotlib import *. But how would I access specific functions like plot() from pyplot and so on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: BigBen - Okay, but what would the simple statement import matplotlib be used for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I import a package into python, do I also have to important it's modules separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371810/if-i-import-a-package-into-python-do-i-also-have-to-important-its-modules-sepa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, `pyplot` is a submodule of `matplotlib` which **will not** automatically be imported just because you import `matplotlib`.

**When you run `import matplotlib as mpl`**, only a specific set of methods will be imported, i.e. you could use `mpl.use()` or `mpl.rc_params` afterwards. If you are interested in what exactly is available to you after importing, try:

```
print(dir(mpl))
```

**When you run `from matplotlib import *`**, the same methods as before are available, just *without* the `mpl.` prefix. That's why you should usually not do this, as you may have planned to write your own function called `use()`.

If you want to actually plot, you'll need to import `pyplot` explicitly, i.e add either:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

or:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Important sidenote:** importing `matplotlib.pyplot` actually further populates the `mpl` namespace; only when importing both `matplotlib as mpl` as well as `matplotlib.pyplot`, you'll get access to the `mpl.ticker` module. If you don't import `pyplot` explicitly, you'll get an `AttributeError: "module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'ticker'"`

[Suggested reading regarding the use of namespaces in python](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-are-python-namespaces-and-why-are-they-needed--cms-28598)